# If select option is selected, change equal select option of other selects to blank

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have numerous `<select>` dropdowns on my page. Each structured *exactly* the same:

```
<select class="position" name="position">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1st</option>
  <option value="2">2nd</option>
  <option value="3">3rd</option>
  <option value="4">4th</option>
  <option value="5">5th</option>
</select>
```

How can I, when I choose `"1st"` in one `<select>`, have any other that is currently set to `"1st"` reset to `""`? Note: I do not want to reset *all* of the dropdowns, only those specific ones.

```
$(".position").on("change", function() {
  var position = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  if (position == 1) {
    $(".position").each(function() {
      // What goes here?
    });
  }
});
```

*N.B.: If someone has a better way of phrasing my question title too, please feel free to edit.*

Comment: I answered but looking over your question again I'm wondering if I misunderstood your question. Do you only care if someone chooses the 1st option and none of the others?

Comment: No, I was simply going to copy/paste the solution, changing the value of `position` each time. The fact that your code manages to do it all in one function is brilliant.

Comment: Great, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var curr = this.value;
  $('select').not(this).each(function() {
    if (this.value == curr) this.value = '';
  })
})
```

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var curr = this.value;
  $('select').not(this).each(function() {
    if (this.value == curr) this.value = '';
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="position" name="position">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1st</option>
  <option value="2">2nd</option>
  <option value="3">3rd</option>
  <option value="4">4th</option>
  <option value="5">5th</option>
</select>
<select class="position" name="position">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1st</option>
  <option value="2">2nd</option>
  <option value="3">3rd</option>
  <option value="4">4th</option>
  <option value="5">5th</option>
</select>
<select class="position" name="position">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1st</option>
  <option value="2">2nd</option>
  <option value="3">3rd</option>
  <option value="4">4th</option>
  <option value="5">5th</option>
</select>
```

Update: If all you're concerned about is the `1st` option, then use this:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $('select').not(this).each(function() {
    if (this.value == 1) this.value = '';
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="position" name="position">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1st</option>
  <option value="2">2nd</option>
  <option value="3">3rd</option>
  <option value="4">4th</option>
  <option value="5">5th</option>
</select>
<select class="position" name="position">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1st</option>
  <option value="2">2nd</option>
  <option value="3">3rd</option>
  <option value="4">4th</option>
  <option value="5">5th</option>
</select>
<select class="position" name="position">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1st</option>
  <option value="2">2nd</option>
  <option value="3">3rd</option>
  <option value="4">4th</option>
  <option value="5">5th</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Pre-empting that I would need the code for every value, and providing a solution that works for them all is just fantastic, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(".position").on("change", function() {
      var active = $(this);
      var position = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

      if (position == 1) {
        $(".position").each(function() {
          if($(this).val()=='1' && $(this)!=active) 
               $(this).find('option').first().attr('selected','selected');
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: This almost works, but it also sets the currently selected dropdown to the first (blank) option too!

Comment: Very nice. I also found that `j08691`'s answer used `.not(this)`, which also works too!